# How do I sort Dojo DataGrids based on dojo.store.jsonrest in the GUI without REST request?

Tags: json, rest, datagrid, dojo, toolkit

I am currently implementing a frontend based on the Dojo Toolkit (1.6.1) receiving a lot of data from RESTful services. This is represented in the GUI by the dojox.grid.DataGrid using a dojo.store.JsonRest-store.

There are however operations used on the grid I do not wish to send a JSON request for, such as sorting a column. Is is possible to allow the user to sort the data without such a request? Can I cache the store information locally (e.g. user browser or in a file) to avoid this?

Any feedback you might have is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I facded the same issue and first tried `dojo.store.cache`, but this is not working.
Hence I created my own cache usind a `dojo.store.memory`:

```
startBuildingCache: function (url, idProperty) {
    try {
        var jsonStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({ target: url });
        var jsonObjectStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({ objectStore: jsonStore });

        var gotItems = dojo.hitch(this, function (items, request) {

            var dataStore = new dojo.store.Memory({
                data: items,
                idProperty: idProperty
            });

            this.cache = dojo.data.ObjectStore({ objectStore: dataStore });
            this.onCacheBuild({
                src: this,
                cache: this.cache
            });
        });

        jsonObjectStore.fetch({ onComplete: gotItems });


    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    }
},
```